# how to export a dictionary into a csv file in python

Tags: python

I have a very big dictionary and want to export into a text or csv file in such a way that keys would be in the first column and values in the 2nd column.
could anyone help to do so?

Comment: [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Comment: `for k, v in d.iteritems(): f.write('{},{}\n'.format(k,v))`

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate through the dictionary and output:

```
with open 'my_csv.csv' as f:
    for k, v in my_dict.items(): # or iteritems in python 2
        f.write("%s,%s\n" % (k, v)) # or whatever format code of your data types
```

Comment: Better to use a `csv.writer`

Comment: Far better. Especially since a "very big dictionary" may well have values of more than one data type.